# Recursive Grouping in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to find a way to create sequential Group_IDs based on "overlapping" variables. The easiest way for me to describe this is using a house, loan, and borrower example.

Assume we have the following example

```
df <- data.frame(house     = c('H_01','H_02','H_03','H_04','H_05'),
                 loan      = c('L_01','L_02','L_02','L_03','L_04'),
                 borrower  = c('B_01','B_01','B_02','B_03','B_04'))
```

Assume that one would have a many to many relationship between all the variables (house, loan, borrower)
So for instance House 1 (`H_01`) is linked to Loan 1 (`L_01`) and Borrower 1 (`B_01`). But `B_01` is also linked to `L_02` which itself is linked to `H_02`, but also linked to `H_03` - therefore the first 3 rows in my table should be labelled `G_01` (for Group 1).

`H_04` is linked to `L_03` which doesn't belong to any other record, and neither does `B_03` relate to any other record, so the fourth record should be in `G_02`. And with analog exploration, we should see that record 5 belongs in its own subgroup `G_03`

Is there a way to elegantly have `dplyr` (preferably, but not necessarily) achieve this grouping of `G_01`, `G_02`, and `G_03`?

Comment: Not my forte, but sounds like networks/igraph.

Comment: For this simple example, the base R code `cumsum(pmin(c(1, diff(df$loan)), c(1, diff(df$borrower))))` will calculate the groups. However, this won't work in general if, for example, an early borrower has multiple loans and shares those loans with multiple borrowers, some early and some late.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for "connected components". We can treat the relationships as a graph by first rearranging the data (`melt`) and then ask a well implemented graph library (`igraph`) to do the work.

```
library(reshape2)
library(igraph)

components(graph.data.frame(melt(df,id="house")[,c(1,3)]))$membership[df$house]

  # H_01 H_02 H_03 H_04 H_05 
  #  1    1    1    2    3
```

To generalize you might want to paste together the relationship with the value to "color" the nodes, e.g.,

```
with(melt(df,id="house"),data.frame(x=house,y=paste(variable,value,sep=".")))
```

before creating the graph.

Comment: Thanks @A.Webb  - this works perfectly and is also very elegant. I've been putting off diving into graph databases but this has just made a compelling example of what I have been missing out on. As a bonus question; does it matter which variable I start the _anchor_ from (in your code you start with the `House` - but if I had n variables, would it make a difference which one I chose to melt around/from?

Comment: It shouldn't matter. This is a bit of a shortcut for a couple of reasons. First, the default graph is directed, which means we specified an edge from H_01 to L_01 and not vice versa. We could/should specify `directed=FALSE`, but `components` by default checks for weakly connected, i.e. as if directed edges were undirected instead. Second, the relationships in the first row are actually H_01 - L_01, H_01 - B_01, and L_01 - B_01, but we've only included the first two as edges. This doesn't matter because the relationship is transitive, as is connectedness.

Answer (score 1):

A. Webb's solution is clearly superior. But since I worked out *a* solution, I'll put it here.

```
df = data.frame(apply(df, 2, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
g = 1
df$group[1] = paste("G",g,sep = "")

#Find out unique groups and assign "CHECK" to rows in same groups
for (i in 2:nrow(df)){
    if (any(df[i,1:3] %in% unlist(df[1:(i-1),1:3]))){
        df$group[i] = "CHECK"
    } else {
        g = g + 1
        df$group[i] = paste("G",g,sep = "")
    }   
}

#Assign groups to rows in same group
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if (df$group[i] != "CHECK"){
        next
    }
    if (df$house[i] %in% df$house[1:i]){
        df$group[i] = df$group[match(df$house[i], df$house[1:i])]        
    }
    if (df$loan[i] %in% df$loan[1:i]){
        df$group[i] = df$group[match(df$loan[i], df$loan[1:i])]        
    }
    if (df$borrower[i] %in% df$borrower[1:i]){
        df$group[i] = df$group[match(df$borrower[i], df$borrower[1:i])]       
    }
}

#> df$group
#[1] "G1" "G1" "G1" "G2" "G3"
```

Comment: thanks as well @d.b - a well thought solution, albeit one that is marginally harder to implement for _n_ variables. Thanks for your very prompt reply